# VS2010 does not break on error when debugging ArcGIS add-in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, add-in, visual-studio

I am having issues with VS2010 and debugging an ArcGIS add-in.   The problem is that when there is an exception, it will not break on it and ArcMap(10.1) just crashes ("ArcMap has encountered....").

I can see the exception in the VS Output window ("A first chance exception. of type ..."), but it's tedious trying to track down where the error occurred.

Also, I have no problems setting manual break points and it will stop at them.

Anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have 'break on exception' enabled? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh.aspx

Comment: Yes, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

This type of project is com project.

In default setting Common Language Runtime (COM) project will not throw exception.

You have to activate it in Debug->Exception (Ctrl+Alt+E) dialog box to break on break points.